# Executing a .net command line application from Perl script

Tags: .net, perl

I have a Perl script that calls a command line application created in .Net.  The .Net application doesn't like being called from the script, it gives the error.

> "Unhandled Exception: System.Exception: Cannot read keys when either
>   application does not have a console or when console input has been
>   redirected from a file. Try Console.Read."

Other than complaining about not having the console, the application works ok.

I'm using back ticks to run the application but I've also tried open, system and exec.  Is there any other way I can fool the .net application to think it's being run from the console.

Answer (score 1):

You want a [pseudo terminal](http://enwp.org/Pseudo_TTY). See [Expect](http://p3rl.org/Expect.pm) and the underlying [IO::Pty](http://p3rl.org/IO%3a%3aPty).